# Least graph containing every connected graph with $m$ nodes as an induced subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, connectedness

- What is the smallest graph that contains every connected graph with $m$ nodes as an induced subgraph ?

  If the graph has $n$ nodes, there are $\binom{n}{m}$ (not necessariliy distinct) subgraphs with $m$ nodes. Since there are $2,6,21,112,853,11117,261080$ connected graphs with
  $3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ nodes, the lower bounds for the required number of vertices are
  $4,6,7,10,13,16,21$ because $\binom{n}{m}$ must
  be at least the number of connected graphs with $m$ nodes.

  But what is the minimal number of vertices required ?

  I found a similar question, where the cases $m=4$ and $m=5$ have been solved ($7$ and $9$ nodes) and it was stated that 
  $n\ge 2^{\frac{m-1}{2}}$

Comment: You can find the similar question unter the "related"-list, first hit.

Comment: For $m=3$, $4$ vertices are sufficient (a triangle and an additional edge). So, the least open case is $m=6$.

Comment: A brief search of the literature seems to suggest the only work done on this problem was in: 

Moon, J., On minimal n-universal graphs. Proc. Glasgow Math. Assoc. 7 (1965), 32–33. He gave the same lower bound you've already mentioned, and a construction for an upper bound.

See the link here:
http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ7_01%2FS2040618500035139a.pdf&code=0bf01e8409ce792c3d961c531b3262e2